# Is there a way to avoid overwriting existing cell values for cells I don't want to post data to? Skip cells?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Let's say I have formulas in "A2" and "A4" and don't want to overwrite it when making an update request. "A1" and "A3" are empty cells. Is there a way to avoid overwriting the data in these cells when I'm inserting my new row data via the python sheets API?
I already tried an empty string `""` as shown below and also `None` as value to hope it will be smart enough to not replace the value if I have an empty str but sadly it's always overwriting my cell values.
I couldn't find anything regarding this and seem to be completely stuck.

This is a simplified example I have a lot of columns so adding every cell value separately isn't a choice because of performance and code complexity.

```
spreadsheet_id = "SPREADSHEETID" 
values = ["my_value_one_first_col", "", "my_value_two_third_col", None]


body = {'values': [values]} result = self.service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheet_id, 
    range="A1",
    valueInputOption="RAW", body=body).execute()
```

Comment: In your goal, for example, for the cell "A1", the cell has a formula and a value by the formula, and you want to update the value without removing the formula. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike No much easier. I only have formulas in "A2" and "A4". "A1" and "A3" are empty cells. So I want to skip "A2" and "A4".

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to put the values from the cell "A5", how about modifying the range from `A1` to `A5`? But if my understanding for your goal is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: A suggestion, could you not first pull the range with the formulas from the sheet, overwrite the values you wish to overwrite in your script and then push everything back, with the formulas unchanged? Because I think the specific thing you are trying to do is not possible, that is, to "skip" cells in a range by leaving their value as `None` or something similar.

Comment: @iansedano Yeah I think that can work. Although the sheets API isn't the fastest and fetching the data takes at least 2 seconds and then writing it 2 seconds again, or even longer depending on how much data needs to be loaded. So that's why I'm trying to avoid the step. I thought I already made it work in the past, by making it skipping cells. But I think I havend used the .update API parameter for it instead used a module. But I'm sadly not sure when and how I did it as it was only for testing.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry I don't get your offered solution. In my list of `values` are only four strings so my range to fill in this case only would be from `"A1:A4"`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I'm worry that I might have misunderstood your question. So in order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample images for input and output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: There shouldn't be any noticeable difference between making one request for the whole range, updating it in memory, and then updating the whole range. In fact, it sounds like you are trying to make a load of small requests, which will actually be slower. Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

In your case batchUpdate() is more appropirate. batchUpdate() takes a different "body" andf rom my experience the body could be dynamic.

Here is a piece of pseudo:

```
spreadsheet_id = "SPREADSHEETID"
values = ["my_value_one_first_col", "", "my_value_two_third_col", ""]

request_get = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range="A1:A4", valueRenderOption="FORMULA")
response_get = request_get.execute()

i=0
for cell_Val in response_get["values"]:
    if "=" in str(cell_Val)[0]:
        DATA_TO_BE_UPDATED.append({
             "range": string,
             "majorDimension": "ROWS",
             "values": [values[i]]
             }
        )
    i = i+1

UPDATE_BODY = {
    "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED"
    "data": DATA_TO_BE_UPDATED
}

request = sheet.values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,body=UPDATE_BODY)
response = request.execute()
```

Comment: Sorry for type. In the for loop, the "range" key should be "A"+str(i+1)